# How can I retrain false positive and false negative labels of a logistic regression model?

Tags: machine-learning, logistic-regression, training-data, precision-recall, false-positive

I have trained a logistic regression model with an extreme imbalanced classes. I used all techniques (SMOTE, class weight adjustment, decision threshold)  to improve performance metrics (Precision and Recall) but results are not very promising - very high false positive class rate :(

I have heard that retraining false positive/negatives could improve the result but I am not sure how the process is. for example should I take false positives, relabel it 50/50 as (1, 0) and train it with the same model? I do highly appreciate if someone can elaborate on process with details:

[image]

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by the relabeling however you should look at `Boosting`.

Comment: would you elaborate on boosting further?

Comment: Um, read about ADA boosting, it'll probably help learn the "outlier" data by punishing the model harder everytime